TypeScript return type conditional on property of input object
I am attempting to write a type-safe API wrapper, which includes a call() function that can be passed an endpoint object describing the target endpoint, request body type (if present), and expected response body type (if present).
If an endpoint.decoder is provided, of type Decoder<ResType>, call() should return Promise<ResType>. Else, call() should return Promise<void>.
Consider the following types:
type Encoder<MsgType extends object> = {
  encode(msg: MsgType): Uint8Array;
};

type Decoder<MsgType extends object> = {
  decode(bin: Uint8Array): MsgType;
};

type Endpoint<ReqType extends object | void = void, ResType extends object | void = void> = {
  path: string;
  decoder: ResType extends object ? Decoder<ResType> : never;
} & (
  | {
      method: 'PUT' | 'POST';
      encoder: ReqType extends object ? Encoder<ReqType> : never;
    }
  | { method: 'GET'; encoder: never }
);

The presence of the encoder and decoder properties determine whether a request or response body is expected for the given endpoint. (Request bodies are explicitly disallowed for GET requests.)
I tried writing the call() function as follows:
async function call<ReqType extends object | void, ResType extends object | void>(
  endpoint: Endpoint<ReqType, ResType>,
  message?: ReqType
): Promise<ResType> {
    let body: BodyInit | undefined;
    if (endpoint.encoder && message) {
      body = endpoint.encoder.encode(message);  // no problem here
    }
    
    const response = await fetch('/api' + endpoint.path, { method: endpoint.method, body })

    if (endpoint.decoder) {
      const data = await response.arrayBuffer();
      /* Error: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'ResType'.
           'object' is assignable to the constraint of type 'ResType', but 'ResType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'void | object'. */
      return endpoint.decoder.decode(new Uint8Array(data));
    } else {
      /* Error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ResType'.
           'void' is assignable to the constraint of type 'ResType', but 'ResType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'void | object'. */
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
}

Since endpoint.decoder has type ResType extends object ? Decoder<ResType> : void, shouldn't the check on endpoint.decoder assert that ResType does extend object, and therefore is not void (and vice versa)?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing and immediately get to work on the problem. If I do that I'm being hit with undeclared Decoder and Encoder, and that void and null are unrelated types and can't easily move forward.

@jcalz Apologies, I have edited my question as suggested.

It is a tricky question, we should look at parameter type ReqType to see what's wrong.
First the function declared a function require ReqType as a parameter type. (ReqType extends (object | void)) is a parameter type the function caller should pass in when calling the function that it requires the pass-in type must extends (object | void)
Therefore ANY Type that extends object could be selected as the ReqType when calling your function, which is decided by the function caller.
Then, as your function claims its return type is Promise(ResType), this actually means you declare your function to return a Promise that contains whatever type the function caller chooses to be the ReqType.
Let say if the function caller choose TypeA = {aaa: string} to be ReqType, your function would accept it because TypeA does extend object. And as your function return type is Promise(ReqType), it actually means your function must return Promise(TypeA).
But this is not what you want. from my understand, you should declare ReqType as ReqType extends object and the return type of your function as Promise(ReqType | void). By doing that, when a caller select TypeA as ReqType, your function will return Promise(TypeA | void)
This relax the function return value to be the param type that user pass in or void. like that
async function call<ReqType extends object, ResType extends object>(
  endpoint: Endpoint<ReqType, ResType>,
  message?: ReqType
): Promise<ResType | void> 


I wanted to avoid having an additional check in the caller to determine whether the Promise resolves to ResType or void. Turns out, a return type of Promise<ResType | void> works as long as overload definitions are present to indicate which occurs when.

oh, i checked your new answer and finally get what you want. But i would like to remind you that such a overloaded function would be pretty hard to understand. maybe it would better to seperate into more than 1 functions.

I managed to solve the problem by using function overload declarations to distinguish the two return type cases (Promise<ResType> and Promise<void>), and relaxing the extends constraint on ResType in the implementation:
async function call<ReqType extends object>(
  endpoint: Endpoint<ReqType>,
  message?: ReqType
): Promise<void>;

async function call<ReqType extends object, ResType extends object>(
  endpoint: Endpoint<ReqType, ResType>,
  message?: ReqType
): Promise<ResType>;

async function call<ReqType extends object, ResType>(
  endpoint: ResType extends object ? Endpoint<ReqType, ResType> : Endpoint<ReqType>,
  message?: ReqType
): Promise<ResType | void> {
  // implementation same as in question
}

The Endpoint type also had some constraints that needed fixing, most notably changing extends object | void = void to extends object = never:
type Endpoint<ReqType extends object = never, ResType extends object = never> = {
  path: string;
  decoder?: Decoder<ResType>;
} & (
  | {
      method: 'PUT' | 'POST';
      encoder: ReqType extends object ? Encoder<ReqType> : never;
    }
  | { method: 'GET'; encoder?: never }
);

